# How to capture video stream of iOS Simulator (Xcode 13)

Tags: streaming, xcode-simulator

I'm searching for a way to capture iOS Simulator video stream.
Video record can be done by

```
xcrun simctl io recordVideo name.ext
```

but how can I capture the stream?

Comment: In your use case, what is the difference between recording video and capturing a stream?

Comment: @nohillside I need the video stream and not wait until the record will finish

Comment: Use something like OBS maybe?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do here. Both of those are about the same. As @nohillside mentioned, there's no difference between them. And with your comment, I still don't get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Thinkr The OP wants to stream the video from the simulator while using it (e.g. to other systems), not wait til it's finished. As they never came back I assume they found a solution but never bothered to document it here.

Comment: @nohillside Ohh. Alright. What a shame they forgot to post it here. :)

Answer (score 1):

The streaming solution of choice is [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com). It has a broad set of options, and allows to stream a window or the full screen to other systems, YouTube etc.

Comment: Yeah, there's loads of video recording softwares that can do this.